# Really confusing error: type 'Screen' is not a subtype of type 'Screen' of 'function result'

Tags: dart

Hi I am writing a Dart app and I am getting the error:

```
type 'Screen' is not a subtype of type 'Screen' of 'function result'.
```

I have literally no idea what the actual error is?

My code is as follows:

```
class CanvasManager {
  Map<String, Screen> _canvases = new Map<String, Screen>();
  CanvasManager (Map<String, CanvasElement> reqCanvas, int sizeX, int sizeY, bool fullscreen) {
    reqCanvas.forEach((k,v) {
      _canvases[k] = new Screen.create(v, sizeX, sizeY, fullscreen);
    });
  }
  Screen getCanvas(String c) {
    if (_canvases.containsKey(c)) {
    return _canvases[c];
    }
    else throw "No such canvas with key ${c}";
  }
}
```

For some reason when I instance that class I get the error.

Just to note `Screen` is a class I have also created. As I'm completely baffeled I don't know if it will help you by giving you that class as well. It's somewhat long so I will paste-bin it: http://pastebin.com/KvZ54yPe

Comment: Just ran it again... Without changing anything and now its a new error: `type 'HashMapImplementation<String, Screen>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, Screen>' of '_canvases@0x1644befe'.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fixed it!

Screen is already a class name in dart:html. The compiler really should tell you if you have reused a class name with some sort of warning but it doesn't.

Comment: Consider filing a bug report asking for better error messages: http://dartbug.com/new

Comment: What Kai said. Also, where did you define your Screen? Libraries have their own scope, so if Screen was defined in the same library as the above code, it should shadow html.Screen. If you're importing both html and a library defining Screen, then you should hopefully see some error on an import about duplicate names.

Comment: Yes, please click "Send Feedback" button in the editor. It should help you out here.

Comment: Here's the bug I created for you, please star it. http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=5871

Comment: Ah didnt notice these comments here, thanks! Starred the issue hopefully I wont run into it again whilst coding