# Strange runtime type exception

Tags: dart

I'm trying to understand the following exception that is being generated by my program.  I have the following code:

```dart
Map<ProjectName,String> userProjects = _ssClient.getUserAccessibleProjects();
ProjectIndexVM vm = new ProjectIndexVM(userProjects);
```

However, when that 2nd line executes an exception is generated:

```dart
Breaking on exception: type '_LinkedHashMap<ProjectName, String>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<ProjectName, String>' of 'projectNameToId'.
```

My constructor is defined as:

```dart
class ProjectIndexVM {
  final Map<ProjectName,String> projectNameToId;

  ProjectIndexVM(this.projectNameToId);
}
```

I don't understand the cause of this error. This substation appears safe to me.  Please advise.

**Updating with requested details**

```dart
class ProjectName
{
  final String Contents;

  ProjectName(this.Contents)
  {
    if(this.Contents == null)
      throw new ArgumentError("Contents may not be null");
  }
}


Map<ProjectName,String> getUserAccessibleProjects()
{
  ...
  Map<ProjectName,String> projects = new Map<ProjectName,String>();
  for(var project in projectsList)
  {
    ProjectName projectName = new ProjectName(project["projectName"]);
    String projectId = project["projectId"];
    projects[projectName] = projectId;
  }

  return projects;
}
```

Comment: My immediate thought is that it is a bug in the compiler - unless you have two different classes named ProjectName, String or Map in your imports for some reason. Try filing a bug report at http://dartbug.com/new

Comment: Can you post the code for `ProjectName` and `_ssClient.getUserAccessibleProjects()`?

Comment: @Dejas Hmm, I can't reproduce this with the posted code. It runs fine for me and does not throw any exceptions. Try copying the code you posted to a new project and continue adding code from your existing project until you get the exception. Then you can edit your question to add the offending code.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there is no other class called `ProjectName` or `Map` (or, god forbid, `String`) in your project or in any imported packages.

Unfortunately, Dart sometimes gives this confusing error (or used to, anyway) when that happens (see [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12878118/really-confusing-error-type-screen-is-not-a-subtype-of-type-screen-of-func)).

If this happens to be the issue, this is definitely a report-worthy bug (which [has already been filed](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=5871)).